# What is the correct WEB-INF path for precompiled JSPs?

Tags: jsp, maven, tomcat, jetty, gradle

My Gradle and Maven builds seems to put precompiled JSPs within different packages.  The Maven build have them in `WEB-INF/classes/jsp/WEB_002dINF`, while the Gradle build have them in `WEB-INF/classes/org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF`.  Are either fine?

Will the compiled JSPs be used on both Tomcat and Jetty, regardless on how they were built?

Here are the relevant parts of my build scripts:

Maven:

```
<profile>
    <id>precompileJsps</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>precompileJsps</name>
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </activation>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-jspc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.mortbay.jetty}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jspc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jspc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Gradle:

```
jasper {
    compilerSourceVM = "1.7"
    compilerTargetVM = "1.7"
    outputDir = file("${buildDir}/jasper")
}

task precompileJsps(type: Compile) {
    if (System.properties['precompileJsps'] == "true") {
        dependsOn tomcatJasper
    } else {
        enabled = false
    }
    group = 'build'
    description = 'Translates and compiles JSPs'
    classpath = configurations.tomcat + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    sourceCompatibility = jasper.compilerSourceVM
    targetCompatibility = jasper.compilerTargetVM
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/classes/main")
    source = jasper.outputDir
    dependencyCacheDir = file("${buildDir}/dependency-cache")
}
war.dependsOn precompileJsps
```

(This question was moved from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19906475/how-do-i-verify-that-precompiled-jsps-are-used-in-tomcat-and-jetty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Each container has its own JSP compiler, internal classes used inside the compiled JSPs, and mapping between JSPs and class files.

You don't get a different result because one build uses Maven and the other one uses Gradle. You get a different result because one build uses the Jetty compiler and the other one uses the tomcat compiler.

Comment: No. If you need precompiled JSPs, you'll have to create two different artefacts. But containers usually provide the option of compiling JSPs at deployment time rather than execution time, if that's what bothers you. And if the goal is to check at build time that your JSPs are compilable, then choose whatever compiler you prefer, and discard the results.

Comment: Thanks.  I was looking for a way to compile JSPs at deployment time, but neither Jetty nor Tomcat seems to provide this.

Comment: Hmm, indeed, I've not been able to find this possibility in the documentation.